# Laravel aimeos: how to get categories with products

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

I use laravel 7.

I want to get products by category from Aimeos and show response by using graphQL.

I use this package: https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel

Unfortunately I cannot use aiemeos method to get data from db and set to graphQl, I can use eloquent queries.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use Closure;
use App\Category;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;

class CategoriesQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Categories query'
    ];

    public function type() : Type
    {
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('category'));
    }

    public function args() : array
    {
        return [
            // No aruments
        ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo, Closure $getSelectedFields)
    {
        return Category::all();
    }
}
```

Here:

```
return Category::all();
```

I get list of categories

I want to get categories with products

Example:

```
Category::with('products')->all()
```

But I cannot find in products category_id or pivot table category_product

Comment: are categories and products two different tables? what are the relationships defined in the models?

Comment: @alex this is the problem that products and categories two different tables, but I cannot find in mysql relations between them, but in aimeos relation between this two tables exists